# Errors (Method must have a return type)&&(' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type')

Tags: c#

I want to make  live feed from the computer’s default camera show in my (ImageBox) that name imgCamUser;
but i see many errors

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Emgu.Util;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.CV;
namespace mmmmmm
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            private Capture capture;
 capture = new Capture();
imgCamUser.Image = capture.QueryFrame();
        }
    }
}
```

but  I have these errors
[image: this error]

[image: this list of errors]

Comment: Drop `private` in  `private Capture capture;` Should be just `Capture capture;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write

```
Capture capture = new Capture();
```

instead of

```
private Capture capture;
capture = new Capture();
```

because variables declared inside a method are only visible inside this method, so it doesn't make sense in declaring them private, public or protected.

Comment: thank you but back new error "Error Cannot implicitly convert type 'Emgu.CV.Mat' to 'System.Drawing.Image "

Comment: that's another question